# python, change json format list to data frame

Tags: python, json

```
*js=['{"id":42352,"user_id":11770,"recipient_id":29936,"exchange_rate_list_id":39298,"send_amount_cents":"73860000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"3000000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"3000000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3336382","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:10:26.751Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:10:26.751Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"708000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42362,"user_id":995,"recipient_id":13068,"exchange_rate_list_id":39306,"send_amount_cents":"37500000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"1875000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"1509500","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3411736","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T10:22:35.831Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T10:22:35.831Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"472000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42351,"user_id":3563,"recipient_id":29935,"exchange_rate_list_id":39298,"send_amount_cents":"8703000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"436000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"350000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4413495","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:08:41.488Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:08:41.488Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"283000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42359,"user_id":2657,"recipient_id":27757,"exchange_rate_list_id":39302,"send_amount_cents":"9937000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"497000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"400000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4369830","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:47:35.891Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:47:35.891Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"283000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42341,"user_id":4472,"recipient_id":29931,"exchange_rate_list_id":39290,"send_amount_cents":"49727000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"2487000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"2000000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"2987161","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T07:45:21.924Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T07:45:21.924Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"472000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42342,"user_id":4471,"recipient_id":17086,"exchange_rate_list_id":39292,"send_amount_cents":"25000000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"1250000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"1005500","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3846653","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T08:07:36.936Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T08:07:36.936Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"354000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42343,"user_id":4471,"recipient_id":12681,"exchange_rate_list_id":39292,"send_amount_cents":"6000000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"300000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"241300","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4506244","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T08:09:24.871Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T08:09:24.871Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"236000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42198,"user_id":9950,"recipient_id":29834,"exchange_rate_list_id":39165,"send_amount_cents":"7453000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"373000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"300000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4451416","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-27T10:58:31.712Z","updated_at":"2016-10-27T10:58:31.712Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"0","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42199,"user_id":2001,"recipient_id":29835,"exchange_rate_list_id":39166,"send_amount_cents":"4969000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"249000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"200000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4537501","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-27T11:00:02.677Z","updated_at":"2016-10-27T11:00:02.677Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"188000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}']*
```

I have a list of string with json format named js.

But when I do

```
pd.read_json(js)
```

I get an error saying

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 pd.read_json(js)
>
> //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in >read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, >keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)
>      209         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, >convert_dates,
>      210                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
>   --> 211                           date_unit).parse()
>      212 
>      213     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:
>
> //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in parse(self)
>      277 
>      278         else:
>   --> 279             self._parse_no_numpy()
>      280 
>      281         if self.obj is None:
>
> //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in >_parse_no_numpy(self)
>      494         if orient == "columns":
>      495             self.obj = DataFrame(
>   --> 496                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), >dtype=None)
>      497         elif orient == "split":
>      498             decoded = dict((str(k), v)
>
> TypeError: Expected String or Unicode

I got it to work by doing

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for j in js:

    data = pd.read_json(j, typ='list')

    df=df.append(data,ignore_index=True)
```

which took forever to execute.

My question is, if I am allowed to read the list one at a time and append that to an empty dataframe, why cant I just read the whole list without getting an error? Is there any way to fix this problem ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
js=['{"id":42352,"user_id":11770,"recipient_id":29936,"exchange_rate_list_id":39298,"send_amount_cents":"73860000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"3000000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"3000000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3336382","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:10:26.751Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:10:26.751Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"708000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42362,"user_id":995,"recipient_id":13068,"exchange_rate_list_id":39306,"send_amount_cents":"37500000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"1875000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"1509500","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3411736","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T10:22:35.831Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T10:22:35.831Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"472000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42351,"user_id":3563,"recipient_id":29935,"exchange_rate_list_id":39298,"send_amount_cents":"8703000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"436000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"350000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4413495","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:08:41.488Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:08:41.488Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"283000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42359,"user_id":2657,"recipient_id":27757,"exchange_rate_list_id":39302,"send_amount_cents":"9937000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"497000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"400000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4369830","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T09:47:35.891Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T09:47:35.891Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"283000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42341,"user_id":4472,"recipient_id":29931,"exchange_rate_list_id":39290,"send_amount_cents":"49727000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"2487000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"2000000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"2987161","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T07:45:21.924Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T07:45:21.924Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"472000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42342,"user_id":4471,"recipient_id":17086,"exchange_rate_list_id":39292,"send_amount_cents":"25000000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"1250000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"1005500","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"3846653","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T08:07:36.936Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T08:07:36.936Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"354000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42343,"user_id":4471,"recipient_id":12681,"exchange_rate_list_id":39292,"send_amount_cents":"6000000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"300000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"241300","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4506244","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-28T08:09:24.871Z","updated_at":"2016-10-28T08:09:24.871Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"236000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42198,"user_id":9950,"recipient_id":29834,"exchange_rate_list_id":39165,"send_amount_cents":"7453000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"373000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"300000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4451416","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-27T10:58:31.712Z","updated_at":"2016-10-27T10:58:31.712Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"0","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}',
 '{"id":42199,"user_id":2001,"recipient_id":29835,"exchange_rate_list_id":39166,"send_amount_cents":"4969000","send_amount_currency":"KRW","commission_cents":"249000","commission_currency":"KRW","receive_amount_cents":"200000","receive_amount_currency":"PHP","save_amount_cents":"4537501","save_amount_currency":"KRW","status":0,"created_at":"2016-10-27T11:00:02.677Z","updated_at":"2016-10-27T11:00:02.677Z","transfer_list_id":null,"purpose":"living_expenses","external_fee_cents":"188000","external_fee_currency":"KRW","sender_country":"KR"}']
a = pd.read_json('[{}]'.format(','.join(js)))
print(a)
```